# crush the height and width of the initWithFrame image size

Tags: ios, frame, rubymotion

I have a small problem with a UIImageView, I try to place an image dynamically so I start like this

```
self.picture_view = UIImageView.alloc.initWithFrame (CGRectMake (0, 16,45, 46))
```

but I want to take my frame size of each image I passed him.

So I do like this.

```
 picture_frame = picture_view.frame;
 picture_frame.size = picture_view.size;
 picture_view.frame = picture_frame;
```

but when I do this

```
NSLog (picture_frame.size.inspect)
```

it gives me 45, 46 for each image,
So how recovered the image size and frame overrider for me that shows the correct size

thank you in advance.

PS: I done well picture_view.image = UIImage.imageNamed (my_picture)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually setting the ImageViews frame to the frame of itself. You need to be doing it based on the actual UIImage. You can do this automatically by initing the view with the image.

Ex.

```
UIImageView *pictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"]];
//The size is already set correctly, but if you want to change the x or y origin do like so

pictureView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 16, pictureView.frame.size.width, pictureView.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is written in Objective-C, but the core idea should translate to rubymotion very easily.

---

If you are trying to create a `UIImageView` and then resize it to fit the `UIImage` you assign to it, you should try something like this:

Create an imageView with an image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPicture.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Change the image, and resize the imageView to fit:

```
UIImage *anotherImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherPicture.png"];
imageView.image = anotherImage;

CGRect imageViewFrame = imageView.frame;
imageViewFrame.size = anotherImage.size;
imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
```